# Probability of three non-disjoint events(likely trivial)

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

This should be a trivial problem at this point, so it is embarrassing to ask, but here it goes:

If I have the probabilities(of just these regions of a venn diagram, given by):
$$\begin{align}\\pr(a)=.2\\pr(b)=.2\\pr(c)=.2\\pr(a\cap b)=.1\\pr(a\cap c)=.1\\pr(b\cap c)=.1\\pr(a\cap b \cap c)=.1 \end{align}$$

Then obviously the total probability is 1. But from my understanding of the equation, I should get $pr(a\cup b \cup c)=pr(a)+pr(b)+pr(c)-pr(a\cap b) -pr(a\cap c) - pr(b \cap c) - pr(a \cap b \cap c)=1.1$ 
${}$
Why is this wrong?

Comment: The seven probabilities that you list do add up to $1$ but that _does not_ mean that "the total probability is $1$" if by that phrase you mean that $P(A\cup B\cup C) = 1$. Nor does the (incorrect) formula for $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ that you state in your question give you $1.1$ as the probability of this event.  The incorrect formula gives $0.2$, not $1.1$ as you claim; the correct formula (told to you in @akhilc's answer; +1 for him) gives the correct answer $0.4$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Don't misunderstand, these are the probabilities of each region of a Venn diagram. You will find that $pr(a)$ on the Venn diagram does contain $pr(a\cap b),pr(a \cap c), pr(a \cap b \cap c)$ hence $.5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's comment

> these are the probabilities of each region of a Venn diagram.

suggests that the OP's question is based on a complete misunderstanding of a
Venn diagram.  An incorrect, but unfortunately very common, Venn diagram
involving three sets shows three intersecting circles creating $7$ regions:
*the rectangle surrounding the three intersecting circles, denoting the
entire sample space, is often missing; even in otherwise-well-regarded
textbooks*. If these
seven regions are marked with numbers that the OP has stated as

> \begin{align}\\pr(a)=.2\\pr(b)=.2\\pr(c)=.2\\pr(a\cap b)=.1\\pr(a\cap c)=.1\\pr(b\cap c)=.1\\pr(a\cap b \cap c)=.1 \end{align}

by which is meant a diagram as shown below

[image]

then in standard mathematical parlance, we have three events $A, B, C$
with $P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c) = 0$, and

\begin{align} 
P(A\cap B^c \cap C^c) &= 0.2\\
P(A^c\cap B \cap C^c) &= 0.2\\
P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C) &= 0.2\\
P(A\cap B \cap C^c) &= 0.1\\
P(A \cap B^c \cap C) &= 0.1\\
P(A^c\cap B \cap C) &= 0.1\\
P(A\cap B \cap C) &= 0.1\\
\end{align}

with the missing region $A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c$ (everything outside
the intersecting circles but in the sample space) having probability $0$.
Thus,
$P(A\cup B \cup C)$ is the *sum* of the seven probabilities, which
is $1$, and the formula quoted by the OP
$$pr(a\cup b \cup c)=pr(a)+pr(b)+pr(c)-pr(a\cap b) -pr(a\cap c) - pr(b \cap c) - 
pr(a\cap b\cap c)$$
(which *looks* like the principle of inclusion/exclusion except for
a typographical error) is completely inapplicable to the situation
at hand: it should have been
$$pr(a\cup b \cup c)=pr(a)+pr(b)+pr(c)+pr(a\cap b)+pr(a\cap c)+pr(b \cap c)+
pr(a\cap b\cap c)= 1$$

Comment: What is the typographical error in the principle inclusion/exclusion part? Thank you for the long and efficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not correct. Last term should be **added not subtracted**.

pr(a∪b∪c)=pr(a)+pr(b)+pr(c)−pr(a∩b)−pr(a∩c)−pr(b∩c)**+pr(a∩b∩c)**

Comment: Should it be $+2pr(a \cap b \cap c)$ and $pr(a \cap b) = pr(a \cap c) = pr(b \cap c) =  .2$

Comment: Since $a \cap b = \dots$ has $a \cap b \cap c$ contained within it